# R add totals to columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `dataframe` like this:

```
a b
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

I want to add a column totals like this:

```
      a b
      1 4
      2 5
      3 6
Total 6 15
```

I am trying to play with `dplyr::summarise` but without luck. Please advise.

Comment: something like `rbind(iris[1:4], colSums(iris[1:4]))`

Comment: @Nate thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the builtin data frame `BOD` try this:

```
addmargins(as.matrix(BOD), 1)
```

giving:

```
    Time demand
       1    8.3
       2   10.3
       3   19.0
       4   16.0
       5   15.6
       7   19.8
Sum   22   89.0
```

It could also be written like this (or use `library(magrittr)` in place of `library(dplyr)` since there is nothing from dplyr used here except what is imported from magrittr).

```
library(dplyr)

BOD %>%
    as.matrix %>%
    addmargins(1)
```